# Installing cancan 2.0 gem in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm having trouble installing the cancan 2.0 gem in Windows XP. I am using Rails 3.1 and in my gemfile y have

> gem "cancan", :git => "git://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git", :branch => "2.0"

but it keeps saying

> No such file or directory - git clone
>   "git://github.com/ryanb/cancan.git"

My teammates are not having this problem, but the are working in Unix systems.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your git is not working properly. Are you using any other git references in your Gemfile?

I copied and pasted the exact same thing in my gemfile and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem 'cancan', github: 'ryanb/cancan', branch: '2.0'
```